# Aggregation of variables by date in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am more used to working  with STATA and have been trying to switch to R, and having trouble getting this aggregation using dplyr/summarise to work.

I have a dataframe with admission/discharge variables, and series of columns with binary (0,1) results indicating drug received on 'DrugDate'.

```
# ID AdmitDate  DCdate     DrugDate   DrugA DrugB .. DrugZ
# 1  03/01/2017 03/04/2017 03/01/2017 1     0        0
# 1  03/01/2017 03/04/2017 03/02/2017 1     0        0
# 1  03/01/2017 03/04/2017 03/02/2017 0     1        0
# 1  03/01/2017 03/04/2017 03/03/2017 1     0        0
# 1  03/01/2017 03/04/2017 03/04/2017 1     0        0
```

Where each row is essentially an series of indicators of what drugs a patient received that day.

STEP 1. 
I would like to first consolidate the dataset like so:

```
# ID AdmitDate  DCdate     DrugDate   DrugA DrugB .. DrugZ
# 1  03/01/2017 03/04/2017 03/01/2017 1     0        0
# 1  03/01/2017 03/04/2017 03/02/2017 1     1        0
# 1  03/01/2017 03/04/2017 03/03/2017 1     0        0
# 1  03/01/2017 03/04/2017 03/04/2017 1     0        0
```

So that there is now one row per day (whereas before duplicate DrugDates existed when more than one drug given on a certain day).

STEP 2

I would then like to create a new dataset that counts "drug days" i.e.

```
# ID AdmitDate  DCdate     TotDays DrugDaysA DrugDaysB .. DrugZ
# 1  03/01/2017 03/04/2017 4       4         1            0
```

Step 2 I figured out how to do, but I thought maybe the community would have opinions about the fastest way to compute as the dataset is quite large. My understanding is dplyr is usually computationally efficient.

I would prefer not to simply do something like:

```
 DF %>% group_by(id, drugdate) %>% summarise(NewVar = max(DrugA))
```

Because there are many variables.

It would be ideal for me to define a list of varnames, then use apply/for-loop to automate the process.

Comment: Looking at your data, it seems you want to count distinct categories and sum the numeric ones. I would create a function such as `f <- function(x) if(is.factor(x)) return(n_distinct(x)) else return(sum(x))` and then simply run `df %>% group_by(ID, AdmitDate, DCdate) %>% summarise_each(funs(f))` which seem to achieve what you need.

Comment: I think this gives me column 5 for step 2? So far for step 1, I have `df2 <- df %>% group_by(id, DrugDate) %>% summarise_at(vars(n:N), max)`, where columns n:N are my DrugA through DrugB variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reshape or `melt` the different drugs into one column using a package like `reshape2` or a tidyverse package.

Then the call to `dplyr` doesn't matter how many variables (drugs) you have.  I provided a simple example bellow that should illustrate the point.  You can extend as needed.

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)

# set up for data
set.seed(5)
n <- 9

#create data frame
df <- data.frame(id = as.factor(rep(1:3, n/3)),
                 date = as.character(sample(size=n, 1:10)),
                 drugA = sample(size=n, 1:2, replace=TRUE),
                 drugB = sample(size=n, 1:2, replace=TRUE))

#melt data
dfm <- melt(df, id.vars=c("id", "date"))

#call to dplyr
dfms <- dfm %>% group_by(id, date, variable) %>% summarise(max = max(value))

> head(dfms)
Source: local data frame [6 x 4]
Groups: id, date [3]

      id   date variable   max
  <fctr> <fctr>   <fctr> <int>
1      1      6    drugA     1
2      1      6    drugB     2
3      1      7    drugA     2
4      1      7    drugB     2
5      1      9    drugA     2
6      1      9    drugB     1
```

To get back into wide format you can use the `cast` functions.

```
> head(dcast(dfms, id + date ~ variable, value.var = "max"))
  id date drugA drugB
1  1    6     1     2
2  1    7     2     2
3  1    9     2     1
4  2   10     1     2
5  2    2     2     1
6  2    8     1     1
```

Comment: I see, and then reshape wide to get back to original format?

Comment: Yes, you can `cast` the data back into wide format however you need.  I edited the answer to include an example.  There is a nice demo here: http://seananderson.ca/2013/10/19/reshape.html